# How do I use sed in YAML file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, yaml, quote

I want to replace `][` with `,` in file `${NGINX_BASE_DIR}/learn-instances.json`.
But an error occurs all the time. I am perplexed about soft quote and `sed`.

```
error: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 27: found unknown escape character

"while true; do sed -i 's#\]\[#,#g' ${NGINX_BASE_DIR}/learn-instances.json; sleep 900; done"
"while true; do `sed -i 's#][#,#g' ${NGINX_BASE_DIR}/learn-instances.json`; sleep 900; done"
```

YAML file:

```
containers:
      - name: retrieve-data
        image: sun-java8-build:3
        args:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - "while true; do sed -i 's#\]\[#,#g' ${NGINX_BASE_DIR}/learn-instances.json; sleep 900; done"
```

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command

Comment: You should escape the brackets `s#\]\[#,#g`. They have a special meaning (enclosing groups).

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are not really using `sed` in a YAML file, as YAML doesn't know about executing
programs. What happens is that you have some program (`nginx` or some plug-in for that?) that loads
the YAML and then inteprets the data, then executes the program specified in that data.

What you need to know is that YAML scalars that are loaded as strings
have different options for escaping special characters. You are using plains scalars (without quotes)
and a double quoted scalar (there are three more styles).

Within plain scalars, no escaping is done, but this means you cannot
use many of the special characters in the scalar (e.g. no `[`, `{`,
`&` or `*`, etc. at the beginning and not `:` + space or space + `#`
anywhere), as these have meaning in YAML.

One thing to do if you have special characters is using double quoted
scalars, but you have to know that a backslash (`\`) has special
meaning in YAML in such scalars. And in your `\]` the backslash is not
followed one of the defined YAML [escaped
characters](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2776092), and that gets you the error.

If you actually want the program that loads the YAML to see `\[`, then in a double quoted scalar,
you need to specify `\\[`. So you could write your last line as:

```
        - "while true; do sed -i 's#\\]\\[#,#g' ${NGINX_BASE_DIR}/learn-instances.json; sleep 900; done"
```

But just doubling the backslashes is not the only thing you need to
take care of, e.g. if the following character needs to be escaped in
YAML as well as for `sed`. Thus  any `\"` in such a scalar needs to be
converted into `\\\"`.

There is a much more easy to write such commandlines in YAML, and that is using [literal style 
scalars](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2795688). Within those scalars, introduced by `|` no backslash escaping
is possible (at the YAML level) and you can keep your commandline as
it is:

```
        - |-
          while true; do sed -i 's#\]\[#,#g' ${NGINX_BASE_DIR}/learn-instances.json; sleep 900; done
```

And actualy, since newlines are preserved in literal style scalars, you might be able to do:

```
        - |
          while true
          do 
            sed -i 's#\\]\\[#,#g' ${NGINX_BASE_DIR}/learn-instances.json
            sleep 900
          done
```

depending on how the program loading and processing the YAML. Since the latter literal scalar is so much more readable than the former, I would certainly try out if that works for you.

(Please note that in both literal style scalars the double quotes at the end were removed)